# How to tell a function is convex but not strictly convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

For example, I know that 4x^2 + 9y^2 + 12xy is convex, but how do I show that it is not strictly convex

Comment: One simple way is try to show the hessian is always positive definite. Are you able to do that?

Comment: well I prove that it was convex by showing the hessian is always positive semi definite, but I don't know how to show that it is only convex not strictly

Comment: This is quadratic. What are the eigenvalues of the Hessian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\;f(x,y)=4x^2 + 9y^2 + 12xy = (2x+3y)^2\,$ is constant along the lines $\,2x+3y=c\,$.